Calculating field rotation between two times
I have the formulae to calculate the rate of field rotation at any given time, and using a python script with Skyfield I can generate a a value incrementing every 10th of a second based on the live data, but is there any way to calculate how much field rotation there has been between now and start of observation ~10 minutes ago without drift?

Below is my current solution, run once to calculate the angle at start of observation, then when run again at any time give you the live rotation angle. It's far from perfect but does work. Unsure if something like this could be improved and included in Skyfield
def fieldRotationRef(self,Object1=None,Object2=None): #both objects in absolute positions

    #Find the angle of Object2 with respect to the plane defined by horizon to Object1
    me = self.obs + self.planets['earth']
    mexyz = me.at(t).position.au
    alt1,az1,dist1 = Object1.apparent().altaz()
    alt2,az2,dist2 = Object2.apparent().altaz()
    alt1r = alt1.radians
    alt2r = alt2.radians
    az1r = az1.radians
    az2r = az2.radians
    alt1 = alt1.degrees
    alt2 = alt2.degrees
    az1 = az1.degrees
    az2 = az2.degrees
    Object1xyz = np.array([math.cos(az1r)*math.cos(alt1r),math.sin(az1r)*math.cos(alt1r),math.sin(alt1r)])
    Object2xyz = np.array([math.cos(az2r)*math.cos(alt2r),math.sin(az2r)*math.cos(alt2r),math.sin(alt2r)])
    Object0xyz = np.array([math.cos(az1r)*math.cos(alt1r),math.sin(az1r)*math.cos(alt1r),0])
    v01 = Object1xyz - Object0xyz
    v02 = Object2xyz - Object0xyz
    cosine_angle = np.dot(v01, v02) / (np.linalg.norm(v01) * np.linalg.norm(v02))
    angle = np.degrees(np.arccos(cosine_angle))

